# Utilizing Javascript 'onbeforeload' on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, dom-events

I am creating a web application that allows gamers to find a partner who is on a similar level. I am using Ruby on Rails 5.

In doing so, I created a player model to store gamer data. This player model works as a queue for my matching algorithm to go through and find a match.

One obstacle to this is that the gamer has to keep the browser open while on queue. If a gamer closes our application or internet connection goes off, the gamer must be removed from queue (= destroy the gamer's player model).

I first approached problem by using javascript 'onbeforeload' or 'navigator.offline'. However, this did not work on rails.

Is there any other approach to keep track of gamer's currnet online status?

Link to my project is at [my github](https://github.com/maerory/Gorankr).

*EDIT*

I have tried using pusher to check its connection status to delete the model.

```
pusher.connection.bind('unavailable', function() {
        <% puts "unavailable" %>
        <% Player.find_by_user_name(current_user.user_name).try(:destroy) %>
    });

pusher.connection.bind('disconnected', function() {
        <% puts "disconnected" %>
        <% Player.find_by_user_name(current_user.user_name).try(:destroy) %>
    });
```

However, it still is deleting only when the page is reloaded. The pusher does not disconnect even after the browser is closed.

Comment: I don't have a precise answer for you, but I can see you are using Pusher. You can probably use this to attach any gamer in the queue to a socket, and check the socket connection state when a match occurs

Comment: @Logar Thanks for your advice, I have tried using Pusher but it wasnt working...